# paste a line with a pattern to the previous line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file with structure

```
"name1";"surname1";23;44
"name2";"surname2 
www.so.org/443";56;33    
"name3";"surname3";223;4554
"name4";"surname5 
surname@so.net";77;889
```

I need an output:

```
"name1";"surname1";23;44
"name2";"surname2 www.so.org/443";56;33    
"name3";"surname3";223;4554
"name4";"surname5 surname@so.net";77;889
```

The pattern here is alphanum at the start of the line and not \". I would like to paste the line with this pattern to the line above.

Edit:

I am using Debian stable.

I have used sed but I realized that it is a stream editor and I thought that it cannot paste a line to a previous one (which is false).
`sed -e 's/^[a-z:A-Z]/ /g'` which only help me to find the correct line.

My second trial was with a text editor. I opened the file with emacs and used `M-x replace-regexp` and find the corresponding lines with `^J[a-zA-Z]` and replace with nothing. It did the job but it also deletes the first character and I need it after a single empty space.

Comment: please add what you've tried.. often such problem becomes easier to solve by reversing the input linewise... for your given example, you could also manipulate output record separator for lines starting with `"` but containing odd number of `"`

Comment: It's good that you know what you want. Can you also tell us what code you used to achieve this goal? Please edit your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;s/;/&/3;t;N;s/\n//;ta' file
```

If the current line does not contain 3 or more `;`'s, append the next line, remove the introduced newline and repeat.

Comment: If the file contains more than 6 `;`'s and the problem is in the third column with thousands of lines. How should I change the sed command?

Comment: @mogan90 if correct line should contain `n` separators then set `s/separator/&/n` and those lines will be pass through without any further sed processing.

Answer (score 2):

This awk one-liner should give you a hand:

```
awk '{printf "%s%s",(/^"/&&NR>1?RS:""),$0}END{print ""}' file
```

The key to the problem is to decide when should we output/print the line break.

This one-liner works for even this format:

```
cat f
"name1";"surname1";23;44
"name2";"surname2
w
ww.
so.
org/
44
3";5
6;33
"name3";"surname3";223;4554
"name4";"surname5
surname@so.net";77;889


awk '{printf "%s%s",(/^"/&&NR>1?RS:""),$0}END{print ""}' f
"name1";"surname1";23;44
"name2";"surname2 www.so.org/443";56;33
"name3";"surname3";223;4554
"name4";"surname5 surname@so.net";77;889
```

Comment: thank you but this one liner also concat surname2 with the rest like "name2";"surname2www.so.org/443";56;33 My file structure is like given in the question.